# AndroidBoostrap preview mode: Font not properly registered

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fonts, android-bootstrap-widgets

I'm using `AndroidBootstrap 2.0.0` for implementing their buttons and icons in my android application but in `AndroidStudio` I always get an annoying exception because of rendering problems in the Graphical Layout Editor. Moreover the button is not displayed in the Graphical Layout Editor, but when I run the application on my device the buttons are shown and working properly. So the error occurs only in the preview mode.

This is the exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Font 'fontawesome-webfont-v440.ttf' not properly registered
at com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.TypefaceProvider.retrieveRegisteredIconSet(TypefaceProvider.java:70)
at com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.IconResolver.resolveMarkdown(IconResolver.java:58)
at com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.AwesomeTextView.setMarkdownText(AwesomeTextView.java:217)
at com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.AwesomeTextView.initialise(AwesomeTextView.java:105)
at com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.AwesomeTextView.<init>(AwesomeTextView.java:68)
at com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton.<init>(BootstrapButton.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:437)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:154)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:93)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:190)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:214)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:142)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:413)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:321)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:511)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:499)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:888)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:499)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:611)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:608)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:365)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:608)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:630)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:643)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:585)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:580)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I added AndroidBootstrap in my manifest as dependency, added `TypefaceProvider.registerDefaultIconSets();` to my `Application` class and imported the `fontawesome-webfont-v440.ttf` font file to my projects `assets/fonts` folder.

Do I miss anything?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't panic you have everything right. :)

This is a bug in the library, the icons should be hidden in Edit Mode. I have raised this to Jamie@BeardedHen and under the GitHub repo.

[GitHub Issue Link](https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap/issues/129)

This will be resolved in the `2.0.1` release, and I have raised a fork request to add `View.isInEditMode()` to the instantiation method.

Comment: this is still an issue in `2.3.2` :
`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Font 'fontawesome-webfont-v470.ttf' not properly registered, please see the README at https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap`